# Hacer una interacción entre dos Google Sheets desde Google Apps Script (Macro)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito hacer una interacción entre dos google sheets por medio de macros ya que necesito usar y escribir datos sobre otro libro para no saturar un libro con bastante información.

Ejemplo:

Tengo una hoja en donde proceso la información de una hoja con mucha información

```
var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('1Z27T52DvYocf4yr1kCPXyB3t5dTobH63PhHjMVENZL8');
```

Al ejecutarlo en una macro de otra google sheet, me tira esta excepción:

> Exception: No tienes permiso para llamar a SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl.
>   Permisos necesarios: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
>   (línea 52, archivo "macros")

(La línea 52 es la variable `spreadsheet2`)

No sé cómo podría lograr que ambas macros se puedan comunicar de dos hojas de cálculo de Google distintas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo arreglé quitando /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */ en la fila 1

Esto es un comentario que se inserta al principio de la hoja y, como lo dice explícitamente, es una librería que hace una autorización manual (para editar Sheets, Docs, Slides, y Forms) unicamente en el mismo. Sin este comentario posibilita hacer que dos hojas interactúen.

Para ver más acerca de esto visita esta página: https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/guides/services/authorization.html

Comment: Por favor sé más generoso con la respuesta. ¿Dónde tenías escrito eso después de todo? No aparece en tu pregunta...

Comment: Lo tenía al principio de la hoja, es un comentario

Comment: Hola Diego, me alegro de que encontraras una respuesta a tu pregunta. Como te indica otro usuario, deberías añadir más información en tu respuesta: ¿qué es lo que hace `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc **/`?¿por qué quitarlo soluciona el problema? También, a a hora de hacer preguntas, si esta es la solución, era imposible saber que éste era el problema y ayudarte sólo con la información proporcionada en la pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [answer]. También completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y así ganarás una nueva medalla).